# Python LoggerAdapter is making duplicate log entries to STDOUT

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to add contextual information to the logging output of my python script. Essentially, I'm using the SocketServer class to handle incoming network connections, and when a client sends a message to the server I want to make a log entry to STDOUT and a file with the time, log level, ip of the client and the message received.

I've tried implementing this using filters (which I couldn't get working, but I'm open to suggestions) and a LoggerAdapter: http://pastebin.com/peT0rjA7

```
class ConnInfo:
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if name == "ip":
            result = tlocal.ip
        if name == "cmd":
            result = tlocal.msg
        return result
    def __iter__(self):
        keys = ['ip', 'cmd']
        keys.extend(self.__dict__.keys())
        return keys.__iter__()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s",
                    datefmt="%d-%m %H:%M:%S",
                    filename="distpovadmin.log",
                    filemode="w")
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
nodeCommsConFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(ip)-4s %(cmd)-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)

#nodeCommsConLogging = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger('NodeCommsConnection').addHandler(console.setFormatter(nodeCommsConFormatter())), ConnInfo())
CommsConConsole = logging.StreamHandler()
CommsConConsole.setLevel(logging.INFO)
CommsConConsole.setFormatter(nodeCommsConFormatter)
nodeCommsConLogging = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger('NodeCommsConnection'), ConnInfo())
logging.getLogger('NodeCommsConnection').removeHandler(console)
logging.getLogger('NodeCommsConnection').addHandler(CommsConConsole)

logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

When I make a call to nodeCommsConLogging like this:

```
nodeCommsConLogging.info("Message Received")
```

I get duplicate entries in the STDOUT log

```
NodeCommsConnection: INFO     192.168.1.8 REQ;     Message Received
NodeCommsConnection: INFO     Message Received
```

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

EDIT: Added code example

Comment: Could you please include the *minimal* code needed to reproduce this behaviour in your question? The pastebin will not last and then your question will be useless for future readers.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot that pastebin entries expire eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Loggers are hierarchical. So you have a root logger (named `''`, i.e. blank). Every other logger is a child of the root logger - eventually.

In your case, you have this hierarchy:

```
 root
   +-- NodeCommsConnection
```

If you log something on the child, it will try to handle it and then pass the log message to the parent logger **unless** you set `propagate` to `False`.

Since you add an appender to `NodeCommsConnection`, it will log its messages using this appender and then call root which will log using its appender -> two outputs on the console.

So either add your appender to the root logger (and remove the default console logger) or set `propagate` to `False`:

```
logging.getLogger('NodeCommsConnection').propagate = False
```

Comment: Great explanation, that's done exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the root logger named `'root'`?   `assert logging.getLogger().name == 'root'`

Comment: Quick and dirty fix is redefining handlers after getLogger:

`logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger') ;
logger.handlers = [logger.handlers[0], ]`

Comment: @Garrett: You're right but that's not what I meant. `logging.getLogger('')` will return the root logger.